# How to rank multiple columns in Excel without duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying my best to rank these two columns, first in descending order by Col. B, then in descending order by Col. C. I am able to find a formula to solve this, but the issue I have is I get duplicates resulting from the second column. I thought to try to add a helper column to bring in the variance between the two columns, but this results in a similar error.

[image]

Here is the formula I am using: '=RANK.EQ($B3,$B$3:$B$21)+COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$21,$B3,$C$3:$C$21,">"&$C3)+IF(D3=0,IF(COUNTIFS($D$3:D3,0)>0,COUNTIFS($D$3:D3,0)-1,0),0)

Wanted table rank is below.

[image]

Comment: What's the rank you want to get for each row? For the two 0 and 50s, both of them being ranked sixth seems correct, unless you want to take into account the order of identical rows i.e. an identical row entered higher in the list should be ranked closer to 1 (like for the two 0 and 0s)?

Comment: I would like the second 50 to be 7, I just don't want there to be a duplicate rank, as I am assembling another table based on these ranks in descending order. I removed the row names from the view above. I added in a second table view which shows the ranks I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the variance column if you're only using it to calculate the rank and can change the last part of your formula to count the number of unique combinations up to that point (of 1st and 2nd). It does the same as your formula but for all variances, not just those that equal 0. So it'll see that it is the second occurrence of 0, 50 so adds one to its rank (2nd occurrence minus 1).

```
=RANK.EQ($B3,$B$3:$B$21)+COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$21,$B3,$C$3:$C$21,">"&$C3)+(COUNTIFS($B$3:B3,$B3,$C$3:C3,$C3)-1)
```

[image: Excel screenshot of problem and formula solution]